# More Values for String Replace in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: replace, yahoo-pipes

I am creating a feed for the NFL teams.

You enter a team, it creates a string, then it uses string replace to create it to an acronym, then it builds the url and fetches the rss feed.

String replace limits me to 10 strings. Is there anyway to expand this to 30 or so strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, chain another String replace right after it :) Chain as many as you need.

If that doesn't work for you for some reason (but it should), then post the link to your pipe so we can have a look.

Comment: It is still showing New England Patriots feed and other feeds. Sorry This is an assignment for my class and before my professor assigned it I had no idea pipes.yahoo existed. 

If you know anything that can better this or make it shorter, I'm always willing to learn. 




http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=c6028caeed9f9c3d470ba1f2db75e528

Comment: The ESPN URL you build doesn't seem to be correct, so it cannot be fetched. Other than that your pipe looks fine, I don't think it can be simplified. About different teams showing up in the result, that's not because something is wrong with the pipe, simply that's coming from the feed. Visit a feed URL directly and you will see, for example http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/teams/was/rss.xml. Or maybe  your professor wants you to filter the feeds.